kmpnotifier throws an error when using two types of koin -> koin core and koin compose
I need koin compose to perform inject viewmodels - > for example
@Composable
fun SplashActivityContent(
    viewModel: SplashViewModel = koinInject()
) {

}

but since I want to use the kmpNotifier library which has a conflict with koin compose I get an error ->
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method koinApplication(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Lorg/koin/dsl/KoinApplicationKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.koin.dsl.KoinApplicationKt' appears in /data/data/ххх.ххх.ххххххххххххххх/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes20.dex)
    at com.mmk.kmpnotifier.di.LibDependencyInitializer.initialize(LibDependencyInitializer.kt:23)
    at com.mmk.kmpnotifier.notification.NotifierManagerImpl.initialize(NotifierManagerImpl.kt:13)
    at com.mmk.kmpnotifier.notification.NotifierManager.initialize(NotifierManager.kt:16)
    at ххх.ххх.ххххххххххххххх.Platform_androidKt.onApplicationStartPlatformSpecific(Platform.android.kt:7)
    at ххх.ххх.ххххххххххххххх.ui.AppInitializer.onApplicationStart(MainApplication.kt:139)
    at ххх.ххх.ххххххххххххххх.ui.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.kt:87)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)

who knows the solution?
